# How to update (RStudio) environment (panel) during testthat::auto_test() runs?

Tags: r, unit-testing, rstudio, testthat

While coding against [exercism problems' tests](http://exercism.io/languages/r/exercises) I noticed that RStudio's (v1.1.359 & before) Environment panel doesn't update its content when `auto_test()` from the `testthat` package is run, and neither when it fails. Setting the [parameter `env`](https://github.com/hadley/testthat/tree/master/R/auto-test.R#L27) to `environment()` or `globalenv()` does not change this for me (R 3.4.0 on macOS).

I'm guessing this is because tests are executed other than interactively.

However, is it possible to coerse `testthat` to somehow update RStudio's Environment panel? So that one can get quick feedback on for example variable values when an `auto_test()` run fails?

Thanks for any hints :-)

Comment: Can you provide any sort of [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to show what you've tried and what exactly the desired result would be?

Comment: Any of the exercism problems can be used that way. For example: `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/exercism/r/master/exercises/hamming/test_hamming.R && wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/exercism/r/master/exercises/hamming/example.R && mv example.R hamming.R`. Then, start RStudio, make the folder of the above downloads the working directory, and run `testthat::auto_test(".", ".")`. Then, introduce some error into `hamming.R`. Is the Global Environments panel updated/populated? If not, how can that be achieved. If yes, what causes that in your enviroment?